Model export error
On the left, I exported one part of my model, but my model ended up rendering the back part of the model, depending on where I look at the model.



Welcome to BSE, can you please give more details about the problem or attach the .blend file of what you're having trouble with?
https://blend-exchange.com

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Here is the blend file :

thank you

After activating the Face Orientation overlay, I noticed that the normals on the object were flipped. To fix this, go to edit mode > select everything > Alt+N > flip. Also, you have attached the .blend1 file, it's used for backups, reattach the file if the problem persists.
